# Generating random names by random character generation is too slow

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this program that creates random words letter by letter to make up random names, but this program runs very slowly. It generates random strings of characters, checks if they are valid names, and then checks if they match a name given by the user.

I tried Cython, but I noticed that Cython only supports Python 2.x. I use Python 3.x.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime

lc_alphabet = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
uc_alphabet = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
lc_vocal = "aeiou"
uc_vocal = "AEIOU"
univ_list = []
verbose = False


def generator():
    name_words = randint(4, 8)
    finished_name = ""
    for i in range(name_words):
        io = randint(0, 3)
        lc_alp_rand = randint(0, 20)
        lc_vcl_rand = randint(0, 4)
        lc_alp_i = lc_alphabet[lc_alp_rand]
        lc_vcl_i = lc_vocal[lc_vcl_rand]
        if io == 0 or io == 1:
            finished_name += lc_alp_i
        if io == 2 or io == 3:
            finished_name += lc_vcl_i
    return finished_name


def name_filtering():
        while True:
            this_name = generator()
            VOCAL_WRONG = False
            CONSONANT_WRONG = False
            univ_wrong_point = 0
            wrong_point = 0
            for y in this_name:
                if y in lc_vocal:
                    wrong_point += 1
                if wrong_point >= len(this_name):
                    univ_wrong_point += 1
                    if verbose is True:
                        print("ALL VOCAL DETECTED " + this_name)
                        VOCAL_WRONG = True

            wrong_point_2 = 0
            for z in range(len(this_name)):
                if this_name[z] in lc_alphabet:
                    wrong_point_2 += 1
                if wrong_point_2 == len(this_name):
                    univ_wrong_point += 1
                    if verbose is True:
                        print("ALL CONSONANT DETECTED " + this_name)
                        CONSONANT_WRONG = True

            for v in range(len(this_name)-1):
                if this_name[v] in lc_vocal and this_name[v+1] in lc_vocal:
                    univ_wrong_point += 1
                    if verbose is True and VOCAL_WRONG is False:
                        print("VOCAL SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)
                        VOCAL_WRONG = True

            if this_name[0] in lc_alphabet and this_name[1] in lc_alphabet and this_name[2] in lc_alphabet:
                univ_wrong_point += 1
                if verbose is True and CONSONANT_WRONG is False:
                    print("3 CONSONANT SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)
                    CONSONANT_WRONG = True

            if this_name[1] in lc_alphabet and this_name[2] in lc_alphabet and this_name[3] in lc_alphabet:
                univ_wrong_point += 1
                if verbose is True and CONSONANT_WRONG is False:
                    print("3 CONSONANT SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)
                    CONSONANT_WRONG = True

            if this_name[0] in lc_alphabet and this_name[1] in lc_alphabet and this_name[2] in lc_alphabet and \
               this_name[3] in lc_alphabet:
                univ_wrong_point += 1
                if verbose is True and CONSONANT_WRONG is False:
                    print("4 CONSONANT SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)
                    CONSONANT_WRONG = True

            if len(this_name) > 5:
                if this_name[2] in lc_alphabet and this_name[3] in lc_alphabet and this_name[4] in lc_alphabet and \
                   this_name[5] in lc_alphabet:
                    univ_wrong_point += 1
                    if verbose is True and CONSONANT_WRONG is False:
                        print("4 CONSONANT SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)
                        CONSONANT_WRONG = True

            if univ_wrong_point == 0:
                return this_name


def search_name(txt):
    disDate = str(datetime.now())
    counter = 0
    number = 0
    while True:
        name = name_filtering()
        name_length = len(name)
        std_space = 10
        fin_space = std_space - name_length
        the_space = " " * fin_space
        if counter == 0:
            print(str(number) + "| ", end="")
        print(name + the_space, end="")
        counter += 1
        if counter == 10:
            print()
            counter = 0
            number += 1
        if name == txt:
            print()
            print()
            print("Name " + txt + " FOUNDED on Number " + str(number))
            print(disDate)
            print(str(datetime.now()))
            break
        sys.stdout.flush()


def check_name(this_name):
    univ_wrong_point = 0
    wrong_point = 0
    for y in this_name:
        if y in lc_vocal:
            wrong_point += 1
        if wrong_point >= len(this_name):
            univ_wrong_point += 1
            if verbose is True:
                print("ALL VOCAL DETECTED " + this_name)

    wrong_point_2 = 0
    for z in range(len(this_name)):
        if this_name[z] in lc_alphabet:
            wrong_point_2 += 1
        if wrong_point_2 == len(this_name):
            univ_wrong_point += 1
            if verbose is True:
                print("ALL CONSONANT DETECTED " + this_name)

    for v in range(len(this_name) - 1):
        if this_name[v] in lc_vocal and this_name[v + 1] in lc_vocal:
            univ_wrong_point += 1
            if verbose is True:
                print("VOCAL SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)

    if this_name[0] in lc_alphabet and this_name[1] in lc_alphabet and this_name[2] in lc_alphabet:
        univ_wrong_point += 1
        if verbose is True:
            print("3 CONSONANT SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)

    if this_name[1] in lc_alphabet and this_name[2] in lc_alphabet and this_name[3] in lc_alphabet:
        univ_wrong_point += 1
        if verbose is True:
            print("3 CONSONANT SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)

    if this_name[0] in lc_alphabet and this_name[1] in lc_alphabet and this_name[2] in lc_alphabet and \
                    this_name[3] in lc_alphabet:
        univ_wrong_point += 1
        if verbose is True:
            print("4 CONSONANT SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)

    if len(this_name) > 5:
        if this_name[2] in lc_alphabet and this_name[3] in lc_alphabet and this_name[4] in lc_alphabet and \
                        this_name[5] in lc_alphabet:
            univ_wrong_point += 1
            if verbose is True:
                print("4 CONSONANT SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED " + this_name)

    if len(this_name) > 8:
        print("TOO LONG (more than 8 letter)")
        univ_wrong_point += 1

    if len(this_name) < 4:
        print("TOO FEW (fewer than 4 letter)")
        univ_wrong_point += 1

    if univ_wrong_point == 0:
        print("this name match criteria")
    else:
        print("this name does not match criteria")

check_name(str(input("Check Name Criteria : ")))
search_name(str(input("Search Name in 4 words : ")))
```

I would be grateful to find out how this code could be sped up. I suspect that `name_filtering` is making it go slowly.

Comment: I used lc_alphabet is just plain variable like so `lc_alphabet="bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"`

Comment: make that a `set`: `lc_alphabet=set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")` and test it again. Could improve a bit, and it's easy to do.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre apparently it doesn't support indexing.

Comment: It is hard to get, what you want to achieve by this code. From a quick look it seems that you have three loops over the same thing (y,z,v all over this_name). Maybe you can combine these to one loop ?

Comment: you don't care about indexing. You want to test _ownership_

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre whoa no, I mean if I do `lc_alphabet[1]` it doesn't work with sets.

Comment: @larwa1n apparently with current logic it cannot because PEP doesn't support a `break` with nested loop.

Comment: @Wowotek yes, but you don't need that. If you need something like that, create a list and then a set from this list to test ownership

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of things that could be done with your code. You had the logic of `check_name` twice, for example - with a little modification, I could modify `name_filtering` to this:

```
def name_filtering():
    while True:
        this_name = name_generator()
        if check_name(this_name):
            return this_name
```

I also reduced some of the logic in `check_name` - eg you don't need to check for both runs of 4 and 3, as you will find a run of 3 if there's a run of 4.

I also implemented sets for membership testing, and added some for loops for brevity, and added `.format` for string interpolation, which led to some speedups. However the real killer was this: `name_filtering` is actually redundant entirely. You can use your criteria to make `generator` (which I've renamed to `name_generator`, as a generator is already something in Python, and `name_generator` tells you more about what it does) always generate a valid name. Your criteria being that there can only be one consecutive vowel, and 1-2 consecutive consonants is quite easy to do within `name_generator`. You simply add a random vowel, then either one or two random consonants.

```
import sys
import random
import itertools
from datetime import datetime

#strings that can use random.choice
lc_consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
lc_vowel = "aeiou"

#sets that support fast membership testing
set_lc_consonants = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")
set_lc_vowel = set("aeiou")

verbose = False

#name generator which now always produces a valid name
def name_generator():
    finished_name = []
    desired_characters = random.randrange(4, 9)
    next_is_consonant = random.random() < 0.7

    while len(finished_name) < desired_characters:
        if next_is_consonant:
            finished_name.extend(random.choice(lc_consonants) for _ in range(random.randrange(1, 3)))
        else:
            finished_name.append(random.choice(lc_vowel))

        next_is_consonant = not next_is_consonant

    return ''.join(finished_name)

#this is now redundant:
def name_filtering():
    while True:
        this_name = name_generator()
        if check_name(this_name):
            return this_name

#shortened logic: if a run of 3 is not present, we know a run of more than 3 is also not present
def check_name(this_name):
    name_len = len(this_name)
    VOWEL_WRONG = False
    CONSONANT_WRONG = False
    univ_wrong_point = 0
    wrong_point = 0
    wrong_point_2 = 0

    for i in range(name_len - 1):
        if all(this_name[i + j] in set_lc_vowel for j in range(2)):
            if verbose  and VOWEL_WRONG :
                #str.format for interpolation from now on
                print("VOWEL SIDE BY SIDE DETECTED {}".format(this_name))

            return False

    for i in range(name_len - 2):
        if all(this_name[i + j] in set_lc_consonants for j in range(3)):
            if verbose:
                print("3 consonants side by side in {}".format(consonant_run))

            return False
    return True

def search_name(txt):
    #no need for str conversion
    start_date = datetime.now()
    std_space = 10

    #counter is implemented by itertools
    for counter in itertools.count():
        name = name_generator()

        #use modular arithmetic rather than extra assignments
        if counter % 10 == 0:
            print("\n{}| ".format(counter // 10), end="")

        #use str.format for space-filling rather than arithmetic
        print("{: <{}}".format(name, std_space), end="")

        if name == txt:
            print("\n\nName {} FOUND on Number {}".format(txt, number))
            #print automatically converts a datetime to a string
            print(start_date)
            print(datetime.now())
            break
```

This code is now quite a bit faster - I tested it like this:

```
$ time python name_generator.py izaak | head -10000 | wc -l
```

Here I'd modified it so you could provide a name to `search` for. I provided my own (invalid D:) name and let it search 10000 lines. With your original code that took about 11 seconds, with the modified version it took 1 second.

Comment: this is actually more advanced while I still use basic programming here and there for example I still use basic Operators. I got the Idea, this is Genius thank you!